# Android Zero touch Potal Not Finding

Tags: android, emm

I have generated a QR using Android Management API and it Working Well but after Flash the policy is not working. Flash is deleting everything. I searched but not found anything expect Zero Touch. But I can't register in Zero Touch. Please help me to register so that i could access Android Zero Touch Potal. In Zero touch is it necessary to buy mobile using the partner ?